# Changing value of textarea

Tags: javascript

I write this script to change the value of a textarea but I fail to do so. What's wrong with my code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementsByName("status").innerHTML = "hi";
            document.getElementsByName("status").title= "hi";
            document.getElementsByName("status").placeholder= "hi";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea placeholder="What's on your mind?" onfocus="window.UIComposer &amp;&amp; UIComposer.focusInstance(&quot;c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333&quot;);" name="status" id="c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333_input" title="What's on your mind?" class="DOMControl_placeholder UIComposer_TextArea">What's on your mind?</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at my answer. its now working, just copy and try it.

Answer (score 5):

Iif you try using:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333_input');
textarea.value = 'hi';
```

It should work.

Otherwise, because of the way `getElementsByName` works, you'd need to provide an index (zero-based) to the call to identify which of the textareas you want to work with:

```
var textarea = document.getElementByName('status')[0]; // selects the first element of name 'status'
textarea.value = 'hi';
```

Comment: That id tag also states to me that it's server generated, which means the full id is not known at the moment of the generation. For asp.net jquery this is workarounded with $('"<%= input.ClientID %>').html("test") which also may work on getElementById. (not name)

Comment: @Jonas, it does look auto-generated, but, and without knowing the server-side language I can't be *sure*, most server-sides can offer a method to reference the correct element.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems

First, `document.getElementsByName` returns a NodeList (which is like an array), not a single element.

Second, you do nothing to delay the execution of the JS until the element actually exists. So it won't find it anyway.

1. Change to `document.getElementsByName("status")[0]`
2. Move the `<script>` element so it appears **after** the textarea.

I wouldn't be comfortable with using `innerHTML` to modify a form control either. I'd switch to `value` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsByName("status")[0].value = "hi";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this script in the body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("status").value= "hi";
</script>
```

change getElementsByName to getElementById

getElementsByName  -> returns array of elements
getElementById     -> returns single control..

then put the script in between body tags not in header.....

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<textarea placeholder="What's on your mind?" onfocus="window.UIComposer &amp;&amp; UIComposer.focusInstance(&quot;c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333&quot;);" name="status" id="c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333_input" title="What's on your mind?" class="DOMControl_placeholder UIComposer_TextArea">What's on your mind?</textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333_input").value = "hi";
document.getElementsByName("status")[0].value = "hi";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I did not see 's' at the end of getElementsByName, this is now correct